# What does Backtrace: Ordinal0 [0x00FE6463+2188387] in stack trace error means while using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Starting to code, so everything is new to me. Been Trying to get this code to work but keep running into errors. I try adding some type of delay since i seen that it might that website doesn't load in time but that does not work.

Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
time. sleep(5)
searchbox = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="search"]')
time. sleep(5)
searchbox.send_keys('Ludwig')

time. sleep(5)

searchButton = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
searchButton.click()
```

**ERORR:**

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 103.0.5060
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 103.0.5060 google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\regra\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\103.0.5060.53\chromedriver.exe] found in cache

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\regra\Downloads\WebAutomationPython-master\WebAutomationPython-master\automation.py", line 5
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\regra\Downloads\WebAutomationPython-master\WebAutomationPython-master\automation.py", line 10, in <module>
    searchbox.send_keys('Ludwig')
  File "C:\Users\regra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 223, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\regra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\regra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\regra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00FE6463+2188387]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F7E461+1762401]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E93C40+801856]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EBCF63+970595]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EBC63E+968254]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EDC7DC+1099740]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB7FF4+950260]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EDC9F4+1100276]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EECC22+1166370]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EDC5F6+1099254]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB6BE0+945120]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EB7AD6+948950]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012871F2+2712546]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0127886D+2652765]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0107002A+520730]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0106EE06+516086]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F8468B+1787531]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F88E88+1805960]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F88F75+1806197]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F91DF1+1842673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76FFFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x771E7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x771E7A6E+238]
```

**ANY HELP WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED**

Comment: I don't know what it exactly means - it can be information about problem inside browser code created in C/C++ (ie. function name and address in memory) - but it is totally useless for you. It can't help you solve problem in your Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [5 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcJ2t.png) match your locator, and webdriver tries to send keys to the first one that is actually not interactable. Fix locator, replace:

```
searchbox = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="search"]')
```

with

```
searchbox = driver.find_element("xpath", '//input[@id="search"]')
```